# Issues with Unresolved references

Tags: python, pycharm

I've read quite a few links but I can't find out a single link that has accurately lists out the steps that need to be followed.

**PROBLEM**

```
> I have the following directory structure (a sample). 
  |MAINDIR
  |script1.py
> |script2.py 
  |COMMONSCRIPTS-------|script3.py                    
> |                    |script4.py                     
  |                    |script5.py 

> |TASK1---------------|script6.py 
  |                    |script7.py
```

I'm trying to import a function in script3.py from script6.py.
But I'm seeing an issue with "Unresolved References" in the imports section.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

Here's what I did.
I set "MAIN DIR" as the "Sources Root" so it's marked blue instead of beige.
Then I invalidated caches and restarted PyCharm but it still hasn't solved my problem.

Can someone please provide a list of steps that I can try to resolve this issue ?

BTW, I'm running PyCharm Community Edition 5.0.4

Comment: What your code looks like? From what I see for now, you will be in trouble importing "COMMON SCRIPTS" as it contains a white space.

Comment: Sorry this was a simple sketch. I've corrected those whitespaces. It was just created to illustrate the problem I'm facing

Comment: Do you have a `__init__.py` file inside the directories that are supposed to be python modules?

Comment: yes I do :) but I've managed to figure out a way to solve this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR - your dirs are not Python modules and your import namespaces may be wrong. Dirs can be easily made Python modules too by adding `__init__.py` like so:

```
mypkg/
 __init__.py
 s1.py
 common/
   __init__.py
   s3.py
 task1/
   __init__.py
   s6.py
```

(`mypgk/`, `common/` and `task1/` are directories obviously)

In `s6.py`:

```
    from mypkg.common.s3 import myfun
```

Note the namespace spec: `mypkg.common.s3`.